# data conversion issue while executing a ssis package

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl, data-conversion, ssis-2012

Executing my package and i am seeing below error. `EMP ID` from source (Flat file) is `DT_STR(50)` and loading it into table:

```
EMP_ID int not null column
```

Using data conversion task i am converting it in to four byte signed integer

But Job is failing.

> Description: Data conversion failed while converting column "EMP ID"
>   (105) to column "EMP ID" (25).  The conversion returned status value 2
>   and status text "The value could not be converted because of a
>   potential loss of data.".  End Error  Error: 2019-09-16 11:37:28.53
>   Code: 0xC0209029     Source: Data Flow Task 1 Data Conversion 0 - 0
>   [2]     Description: SSIS Error Code
>   DTS_E_INDUCEDTRANSFORMFAILUREONERROR.  The "Data Conversion
>   .Outputs[Data Conversion Output].Columns[EMP ID]" failed because error
>   code 0xC020907F occurred, and the error row disposition on "Data
>   Conversion 0 - 0.Outputs[Data Conversion Output].Columns[EMP ID]"
>   specifies failure on error. An error occurred on the specified object
>   of the specified component.  There may be error messages posted before
>   this with more information about the failure.  End Error  Error:
>   2019-09-16 11:37:28.53     Code: 0xC0047022     Source: Data Flow Task
>   SSIS.Pipeline     Description: SSIS Error Code
>   DTS_E_PROCESSINPUTFAILED.  The ProcessInput method on component "Data
>   Conversion (2) failed with error code 0xC0209029 while processing
>   input "Data Conversion Input" (3). The identified component returned
>   an error from the ProcessInput method. The error is specific to the
>   component, but the error is fatal and will cause the Data Flow task to
>   stop running.  There may be error messages posted before this with
>   more information about the failure.  End Error  DTExec: The package
>   execution returned DTSER_FAILURE (1).  Started:  11:37:27 AM 
>   Finished: 11:37:28 AM  Elapsed:  0.797 seconds.  The package execution
>   failed.  The step failed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main error is:

> The conversion returned status value 2 and status text "The value could not be converted because of a potential loss of data

It looks like that the source column contains values that cannot be converted to integer, you can configure the error output to redirect bad rows to a flat file destination in order to check the values that are causing this error.

[image]

[image]

[image]